# How to parameterize element locators in pytest playwright

Tags: python, pytest, playwright, webautomation, testautomationfx

How to write an element locator of which the text value could be parameterized in Pytest Playwright.

Eg:  We can do it like this in Selenium,

- initially define a string: `String product_code = form[@data-id='PRODUCT_CODE']`
- and then updating the variable value by: `By.xpath(lbl.replace("PRODUCT_CODE", product)`

How can we achieve the same in pytest playwright for an element locator with `get_by_text`?

I have tried the following and didn't work.

```py
test_fav_list = page.query_selector(f'[name="{self.element_name}"]')
element_name = name
test_fav_list.click()
element = self.page.query_selector(f'[name="{name}"]')
if element:
    element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Query selector returns an element handle, which is outdated and discouraged by the playright [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle). I recommend following the documentation's advice and switch to using `locator`s.

Using your code, it might look something like this:

```
test_fav_list = page.locator(f'[name="{self.element_name}"]').click()
self.page.locator(f'[name="{name}"]').click()
```

This should fix your issue.